# Share a folder programatically with custom credentials

Tags: windows, networking, network-share

Is it possible to share a windows folder with custom credentials (rather than a windows account)?

I'm developing internet cafe software. I want to mount a desktop folder from a network share upon login. This way they will have easy access to their files. We currently have over 10,000 registered users and over 200 computers. Each user should have access to his own network folder, using his own username and password.

I want different network credentials to make everything secure. If I use a global user/pass and someone figures it out, he will be able to access all files.

(I can use windows or linux for the server.)

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve here?  Is this some kind of business or application requirement?  It sounds like the type of administrative mess that Active Directory/windows credentials are supposed to prevent.

Comment: I'm developing an internet cafe software .  People login and i want to mount desktop folder from a network share .  This way they will have easy access to their files .   We currently have over 10 000 registered users  and over 200 computers .  I want different network credentials to make everything secure  . If I use a global user/pass and someone figures it out, he will be able to access all files .

Comment: It kind of sounds to me like you're rewriting [roaming profiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  There's also a [samba implementation](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_&_Windows_Profiles). Either way, I just voted to migrate this to Stack Overflow, because it sounds like more of a programming question.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Possible?.... sort of.

You would have to use windows credentials to access the file on behalf of the "non-windows" credentials.

But first of all.... If these 10k users are windows users... Just set them up in AD to have their own homedir.  If this isn't possible, then yes you could theoretically make this happen... but it seems like a nightmare to manage.

Comment: They are not windows users . They login in my software and then I want to  map their Desktop to their network folder . If I use a global user/pass and someone figures it out, he will be able to access all files and i want to prevent that.

Comment: When you say "login in my software" and "map their Desktop"  are we talking Windows desktop or a desktop in your software?

Comment: Also, what I meant about "on behalf of the user" was to have the application have the rights to perform this funcion (server side).